# How to translate resource dynamically ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question with ngx-translate. I dont know how to make a dynamically resource translate in html.
For instance:

i18n

```
    "agreement.status.0": "New",
    "agreement.status.1": "Rejected",
```

html

```
   <span>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{'choiceType' | translate}}</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAgreementType">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let state of agreementStates" [value]="state.id">
                    {{ 'agreement.status.' + state.id | translate}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </span>
```

I dont know how to connect this constant string with variable

Answer (score 2):

You can get help from backend;

```
translate(id){
return this.translate.instant('agreement.status.' + id);
}
```

and use it like

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of agreementStates" [value]="state.id">
{{translate(state.id) }}
<mat-option>
```

Comment: running functions in a template is a bad idea.

Comment: why a bad idea ?

Comment: because functions in templates are evaluated on every run of the change detection.
https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 0):

You can `'agreement.status' | translate` in alias and use it in options.

```
 <span *ngIf="('agreement.status' | translate) as status">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{'choiceType' | translate}}</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAgreementType">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of agreementStates" [value]="state.id">
                {{ status[state.id] }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
 </span>
```

[**Sample Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-example-ussjlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @Soft this works for me, I created stackblitz for your problem, it works perfectly fine. Please check

Comment: @Soft  have you get time to check stackblitz?